# Failing to browse React application deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, eslint

> When wirite https://tictactoesko.herokuapp.com/ in a browser then I
>   recive folowing error message:
>
> Failed to compile ./src/index.js Module build failed: Error: Cannot
>   find module 'eslint/lib/formatters/stylish'
>
> My index.js look like this
>   import React from 'react'
>   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
>   import './index.css'
>   import Game from './Game'

ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'))

> My package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "tic-tac-toe",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "eslintConfig": {
    "env": {
      "es6": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 8,
      "sourceType": "module",
      "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
      }
    },
    "extends": [
      "standard",
      "react-app",
      "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended" 
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "jsx-a11y",
      "react"
      ],
    "rules": {
      "no-trailing-spaces": "off",
      "padded-blocks":"off",
      "jsx-a11y/href-no-hash":"off"
   }
  },
  "jest": {
    "testMatch": [
      "**/test/**/*.js?(x)"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 100,
        "functions": 100,
        "lines": 100,
        "statements": 100
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^2.35.0",
    "jest-cli": "^22.3.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint  src/** test/** ",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "^22.2.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "cypress": "^2.0.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint": "^4.18.1",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.9.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.46.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "jest": "^22.3.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0"
  }
}
```

> Here is the travis.yml
>   language: node_js node_js:
>   - node addons:   sonarcloud:  before_script:
>   - npm start -- --silent & script:
>   - npm run lint
>   - npm test
>   - sonar-scanner  -Dsonar.projectKey=TicTacToe -Dsonar.organization=steinko-github   -Dsonar.sources=src,test -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io -Dsonar.login=6472ac35c070752487408fd8c946cca6b536eec2   -Dsonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
>   - $(npm bin)/cypress run --record --key a1319fd9-2c6e-4888-8f02-e62f02b5001b deploy:   provider: heroku
>   api_key:
>       secure: 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
>   app: tictactoesko
>
> And the deployment log feom Heroku looks like this
>   Building dependencies
>          Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
>          up to date in 11.521s
>   -----> Caching build
>          Clearing previous node cache
>          Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
>          - node_modules
>          - bower_components (nothing to cache)
>   -----> Build succeeded!
>   -----> Discovering process types
>          Procfile declares types     -> (none)
>          Default types for buildpack -> web
>   -----> Compressing...
>          Done: 57.4M
>   -----> Launching...
>          Released v11
>          https://tictactoesko.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
>
> When wirite https://tictactoesko.herokuapp.com/ in a browser then I
>   recive folowing error message:
>
> Failed to compile ./src/index.js Module build failed: Error: Cannot
>   find module 'eslint/lib/formatters/stylish'
>   How could i correct this error?

Answer (score 2):

You installed `eslint` manually and this can break things. You should uninstall it and edit just your `.eslintrc` file. Look the comments of @gaearon in this Github [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3617)

But if you wish to control directly and customize everything. I would eject the project: `npm run eject`. Check the guide of [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject).