# React app cant able to deploy into github

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, build, command-line-interface

Getting below error . Please someone help me.

Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'eslint/lib/formatters/stylish'

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-oscar@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-oscar@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\indu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-11T23_24_41_507Z-debug.log

Regards
Indu

Comment: check this maybe it will help, https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-loader/issues/271

Comment: looks similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022912/failing-to-browse-react-application-deployed-to-heroku